# Infopath Form Submission Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I created a Submit Data Connection on Infopath for a Sharepoint List. The Submit Location is the same as the Main Data Connection, however:

-When I use the Main Data Connection to submit, I get an error on submission that the File Name already exists on Sharepoint

-When I use my custom Data Connection to submit, the pop up says the form has been submitted. But the data isn't present in the Sharepoint List.

Comment: How did you customize the list? Via LIST->Customize Form button? How did you set the Submit button? is there any rule on it?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on the second issue, but the first issue is occurring because Overwriting Existing files is disabled and your filename is being set in a way that however you are filling out the form, result in duplicate names.

One way to easily prevent files from overlapping in name is to include the Date/time in the file name (This is not always the desirable behavior. Depending on the situation, these settings may need to change).

Comment: I cannot deselect this, since it is the default Infopath Data Connection.

Comment: Are you able to change the filename?

Comment: Not in the Main Data Connection